# How to connect to Sybase SQL Anywhere 5 database running on 9 server using native ADO.NET?

Tags: ado.net, connection-string, sybase, sqlanywhere

SQL Anywhere used to come bundled with Sybase Powerbuilder, and now is the property of SAP. From version 5 to version 12 something changed, and when trying to open an ADO.NET connection, it tries to execute a CHAINED=on parameter after opening. It keeps doing it even in version 17, and I don't know how to stop it from doing that on this connection to this database. I don't know if the database does not support it or the server is the one that doesn't. No one knows how to upgrade the database or the server.

We are trying to connect because via ODBC a simple query times out, so we want to try changing the driver (using SA objects instead of ODBC objects). If this fails we will have to change the way the code is retrieving the data so as to not trigger the timeout.

Since all drivers from 12 to 17 trigger the chained option, we went back to the version 9 driver, which you have to manually add a reference to the dll to.

Once we added the reference and changed all the code to ASA objects instead of SA objects, we tried opening the connection and the connection string couldn't be parsed.

The Sybase Central 9 app does not work in windows 7 nor windows 10, so we couldn't generate a connection string that way.

What can the correct connection string be for an asaconnection? ConnectionStrings.com isn't any help. Read on to find out!

Answer (score 0):

"ENG=dbservername;DBN=databasename;UID=userid; PWD=password;LINKS = tcpip(host = ipaddress;port=theport)"

Capitalization IS important it seems.

So, to connect to this legacy database from ADO.NET DO NOT use drivers from 12 to 17, use the 9 version driver, and that particular connection string.

If someone knows how to stop the version 12 onwards drivers from firing off that chained option, or how to add support for that option to a version 5 database running on a version 9 server, feel free to share.